# Even though I send bearer token inside the Axios , it returns as unauthorized

Tags: reactjs, axios, local-storage, interceptor, bearer-token

In my react app I am using axios to perform the REST api requests.

However, when I send the Authorization header with the request, it returns `401` code, what should I do?

Here is my code:

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { BASE_URL } from "@configs";

export const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  // https://xyz.abc.com
});

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  }
  return config;
});
```

My App.js:

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect } from "react";

// ** Router Import
import Router from "./router/Router";
import { axios } from "@lib/axios";

const App = () => {
  const getAllData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios(`/data`);
      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <Router />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default App;
```

vite.config.js:

```
import fs from "fs";
import * as path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";
import NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";

export default () => {
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    define: {
      global: "globalThis",
    },
    server: {
      port: 3000,
      proxy: "https://pixinvent.com/",
      cors: {
        origin: ["https://pixinvent.com/", "http://localhost:3000"],
        methods: ["GET", "PATCH", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
        allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With"],
      },
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          includePaths: ["node_modules", "./src/assets"],
        },
      },
      postcss: {
        plugins: [require("postcss-rtl")()],
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: [
        {
          find: /^~.+/,
          replacement: (val) => {
            return val.replace(/^~/, "");
          },
        },
        { find: "stream", replacement: "stream-browserify" },
        { find: "crypto", replacement: "crypto-browserify" },
        { find: "@src", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src") },
        { find: "@store", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/redux") },
        {
          find: "@configs",
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/configs"),
        },
        {
          find: "url",
          replacement: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/url",
        },
        {
          find: "@styles",
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/@core/scss"),
        },
        {
          find: "util",
          replacement: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util",
        },
        {
          find: "zlib",
          replacement: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/zlib",
        },
        {
          find: "@utils",
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utility/Utils"),
        },
        {
          find: "@hooks",
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utility/hooks"),
        },
        {
          find: "@assets",
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/@core/assets"),
        },
        {
          find: "@layouts",
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/@core/layouts"),
        },
        {
          find: "@lib",
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/lib"),
        },
        {
          find: "assert",
          replacement: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/assert",
        },
        {
          find: "buffer",
          replacement: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/buffer-es6",
        },
        {
          find: "process",
          replacement: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/process-es6",
        },
        {
          find: "@components",
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/@core/components"),
        },
      ],
    },
    esbuild: {
      loader: "jsx",
      include: /.\/src\/.*\.js?$/,
      exclude: [],
      jsx: "automatic",
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
      esbuildOptions: {
        loader: {
          ".js": "jsx",
        },
        plugins: [
          NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
            buffer: true,
            process: true,
          }),
          {
            name: "load-js-files-as-jsx",
            setup(build) {
              build.onLoad({ filter: /src\\.*\.js$/ }, async (args) => ({
                loader: "jsx",
                contents: await fs.readFileSync(args.path, "utf8"),
              }));
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        plugins: [rollupNodePolyFill()],
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Maybe the issue come from here?
I tried with the normal axios headers method, but I got the 401 code again, maybe I need to recognize it here. When I try it in Postman, I can get the data.

Comment: We need some additional informations, what framework are you using for the server and also, `await axios('/data');` should be `await axios.get('/data');`.

Comment: I didn't write the backend but it uses nestjs which is the node.js framework. and axios.get() and axios() return the same value and work, I think just get, post, delete etc. It works for and it is necessary to use dot notation

Comment: Please add the nestjs code where you validate the bearer token. The problem seems to be with the server side. But you should also try to add headers to the axios request to make sure the token is send correctly in the authorization header: `await axios('/data', { 
headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("accessToken") ?? ''}' } });`

Comment: I got the same result as you said, `401` code, but when I try it in Postman, the data return `200`. I shared the `vite.config.js` above, could it be due to this, or is there something I need to define, I am using web pack for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { BASE_URL } from "@configs";

export const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  // https://xyz.abc.com
});

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  }
  return config;
});
```

The issue was mine because I used the data without parsing, I overlooked it, when I did it like this, it was fixed.